# How can I download a pip whl, change the version of dependencies and build a whl file again to install it with pip?

Tags: python, installation, pip, pysyft

I want to install PySyft via pip on a Jetson TX2.
Unfortunately, I have a big problem with the dependencies here and the Jetson TX2. As an example, I want to change the dependency torch==1.4.0 to torch>=1.4.0 or torch==1.6.0 because I can't install another torch version for the Jetson.

I have already tried the following:

`python3 -m pip download -w syft==0.2.3a1 --no-deps`

and get a syft-0.2.3a1-py3-none-any.whl which I can unzip and read out the dependencies via the METADATA.
Can I change it now as described above and build a *.whl again to install it using pip afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Just... modify the extracted METADATA, recompress into a zip and rename to the same name as the original wheel?

While you're at it, you may want to increment or change the version of the modified package.

Answer (score 2):

> Just... modify the extracted METADATA, recompress into a zip and rename to the same name as the original wheel?

I tried this approach and get some errors when repack.

A functional approach (maybe need more optmization):

- unpack with `wheel unpack <file.whl>`;
- rename folders;

  - `mkdir` newfolders;
  - `cp` files;
  - `rm` old folder
- delete `RECORD`file;
- repack with `wheel pack <renamed-folder>`.

I do that with this [script](https://gist.github.com/lunhg/6cc9f4642aee8a8a1151288e6a522e38).